# timer flicks after button press

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I am trying to put a timer on an app. I am using the code below and it works onCreate. But if press the button a second time the seconds are starting to mess up and flick a little bit.
Any ideas?

```
 package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int counter;
    TextView timer;
    Button button;
    private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View V) {
                new CountDownTimer(2400000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        timer.setText (String.format(FORMAT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));


                                }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        timer.setText("done!");
                    }
                }.start();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you click again when the text is done? Or just as it ticks?

Comment: i try it as it ticks

Comment: Okay I got you! You are having a number of instances of the timer!

Comment: Check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage a single instance of `CountDownTimer` in your whole `Activity`. You are having a number of instances on the same `Activity` it may get messy. First outside your `onCreate` but inside your class start by declaring it as

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
```

Then in your `Button`'s onClickListener `onClick` method do this:

```
if(countDownTimer!=null){
   countDownTimer.cancel();
}
countDownTimer= new CountDownTimer(2400000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timer.setText (String.format(FORMAT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));


                            }

                public void onFinish() {
                    timer.setText("done!");
                }
            }.start();
```

From here you will be managing only one instance of the class instead of creating a lot more on each button click.

Comment: is there any chance the countDownTImer gets null?

Comment: Yeah when you click the button for the first time! because it has not been initialized yet! I like your question!

Comment: it has NOT been initialized yet if you click the button for the first time!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I got how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The CountDownTimer could be flickering over the old instance of itself. Try calling cancel() before restarting the count down.